# How to access nested value belonging to a specific value

Tags: json, ruby

I have a trouble to access some data.

I have this file :

```
SUPPLIERS = [
{ name: "FunePlus", advitam_grade: 3, works: [ { type: "embalming", price: 350 }, {type: "transport_before_casketing", price: 450} ]},
{ name: "FuneTop", works: [ { type: "graving", price: 10 } ]},
{ name: "FuneTruc", advitam_grade: 5, works: [ { type: "embalming", price: 750 }]},
{ name: "FuneCorp", advitam_grade: 2, works: [ { type: "digging", price: 350 }]}
]



class SelectSupplier
  def self.global_grade(name)

  end
end

SelectSupplier.global_grade("FunePlus")
```

When I call the method `global_grade`, I want to join a specific name and then return the associated values.

Here's the output I'm looking for :

```
SelectSupplier.global_grade("FunePlus")
 :advitam_grade=>3, :works=>[{:type=>"embalming", :price=>350}, {:type=>"transport_before_casketing", :price=>450}]}
```

Does some of you have any idea of how I could do that ?

Comment: What result do you get when you try `SelectSupplier.global_grade("FunePlus")`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by using `Array#find` method:

```
SUPPLIERS = [
{ name: "FunePlus", advitam_grade: 3, works: [ { type: "embalming", price: 350 }, {type: "transport_before_casketing", price: 450} ]},
{ name: "FuneTop", works: [ { type: "graving", price: 10 } ]},
{ name: "FuneTruc", advitam_grade: 5, works: [ { type: "embalming", price: 750 }]},
{ name: "FuneCorp", advitam_grade: 2, works: [ { type: "digging", price: 350 }]}
]



class SelectSupplier
  def self.global_grade(name)
      SUPPLIERS.find {|x| x[:name] == name }
  end
end

SelectSupplier.global_grade("FunePlus")
```

This will return the first hash that matches your `name` parameter

Answer (score 0):

@John has told you how to extract the desired hash. If you wish to do this multiple times, for different values of the key `name`, you should consider the one-time construction of a hash to speed look-ups.

```
SUPPLIERS = [
  { name: "FunePlus", advitam_grade: 3, works: [ { type: "embalming", price: 350 }, 
    { type: "transport_before_casketing", price: 450} ]},
  { name: "FuneTop",                    works: [ { type: "graving", price: 10 } ]},
  { name: "FuneTruc", advitam_grade: 5, works: [ { type: "embalming", price: 750 }]},
  { name: "FuneCorp", advitam_grade: 2, works: [ { type: "digging", price: 350 }]}
]

class SelectSupplier
  @supplier_index = SUPPLIERS.each_with_index.with_object({}) { |(g,i),h| h[g[:name]] = i }
  def self.global_grade(name)
    SUPPLIERS[@supplier_index[name]]
  end
end

SelectSupplier.global_grade("FunePlus")
  #=> {:name=>"FunePlus", :advitam_grade=>3, :works=>[{:type=>"embalming", :price=>350},
  #     {:type=>"transport_before_casketing", :price=>450}]}
```

The hash `@supplier_index` equals the following.

```
SelectSupplier.instance_variable_get(:@supplier_index)
  #=> {"FunePlus"=>0, "FuneTop"=>1, "FuneTruc"=>2, "FuneCorp"=>3}
```

Note that I could have constructed `@supplier_index` with values equal to the elements of `SUPPLIERS` (hashes) but that would have increased memory requirements (which may not be a problem, of course).